# peerconnection_client does not show the list of peers

Tags: sockets, webrtc, peer-connection

Here I'm trying to run some of samples available in the WebRTC codes...
I run the peerconnection_server.exe on my machine (laptop, running Windows 8.1) it successfully runs.
I also run 2 clients via the peerconnection_client.exe. On the peerconnection_server I see the following:

> Server listening on port 8888 New connection... 
>  New member added
>   (total=1): lkarapetyan@SYS0700 
>  Disconnecting socket 
>  Total
>   connected: 1 
>  New connection... 
>  New connection... 
>  New
>   member added (total=2): lkarapetyan@SYS0700 
>  Disconnecting socket
>   
>  Total connected: 2 
>  Disconnecting socket 
>  Total
>   connected: 2 
>  New connection... 
>  New connection...

Assuming this means that both clients were successfully connected. However, on the client side the list of connected peers remains empty (also tried to run another client on another machine and connect to the server, the result is the same).

Why the list of connected peers is not shown in the peerconnection_client? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same Problem. You should look at the issue 4244 in the WebRTC issue tracker below. My understanding is that the issue is now fixed so sychronizing the repository to the current Version 8335 should solve it. I solved it before by creating my own peerconnection_server Project in Visual Studio. It is quite simple - just create a new console Project, replace the sources with the sources of the peerconnection_server Project and remove all code which has dependencies to the rest of the webRTC repository. Just the command line handling causes a dependency. Strip that off. The rest of the peerconnection_server is Independent from the webRTC sources and you can compile and modify it quite simply according your needs if the issue 4244 should not yet be fixed.

To test wheter your Server works correctly look at
http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development - paragraph "Testing peerconnection_server".

https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=4244&can=1&q=peerconnection_server&colspec=ID Pri Mstone ReleaseBlock Area Status Owner Summary

Comment: Thank you so much!
I just fixed the incorrect code mentioned in 4244 and now it works. ( Though, I have not updated the webRTC codes yet to see if it was fixed, but probably it is :) )